# Sharing asset library video on ios with swift

Tags: ios, swift, video, swift2

I save a video file to Library and  then try to share the NSURL of the asset library with UIActivityViewController.

For some apps like viber it works, but some other like whatsapp and Gmail the URL is shared instead of video file itself.

here is an example
assets-library://asset/asset.mov?id=944F2398-FE49-44EA-9AF1-41EBC017EA64&ext=mov

any idea how to share the video file from library with Swift and UIActivityViewController ?

```
let activityViewController : UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [videoURL], applicationActivities: nil)
self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the actual physical **file** path. Example URL:

> file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/path-to-my-videos-folder/my-video.mp4

One issue that I see happening with your journey is that the share dialog will have the option to save to library again, so feels like you're spinning in circle there.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I just saw that it was asked a year ago. Oh well :)